# Override dictionary constructor for a WCF DataMember

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, datacontract

Is it possible specify which constructor the WCF serialization engine uses when deserializing a data member?

For example: I want to use this constructor to make a case-insensitive dictionary without creating a new class that inherits from Dictionary.

```
[DataMember]
Dictionary<string, string> Values { get; set; }

// Values should be created with this constructor
new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible specify which constructor the WCF serialization engine uses when deserializing a data member?

No it isn't, unless you use implement your custom serialization.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 3):

If you provide an implementation of your property setter method, you can instantiate for yourself the new case-insensitive Dictionary instance which will be the value of the property, and just copy into it the items from the instance provided by the serializer as the `value` parameter.

You'll need to be prepared to handle any exceptions due to key clashes if the source of the serialized Dictionary was case-sensitive.

Comment: Interesting idea.  This is exactly how I overcome some other serialization limitations.  The only annoying part is the creation of the additional dictionary.